# BootStrap 3 - NavBar Collapse Button is not Working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've copied this navbar from Bootsrap page and the collpase button is not working any ideas why?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>
                <a href="index.html"><img class="block" id="logo" src="images/logo.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">VGO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="vIRL.html">vIRL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="csgo.html">CS:GO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="trading.html">TRADING</a></li>                        
                    <li><a href="cashout.html">CASHOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Your navbar works fine, assuming you have correctly referenced both jQuery and the required Bootstrap JavaScript file. If yours is not working, it is simply because you have not referenced the two JavaScript files correctly. Remember, jQuery must be referenced *before* Bootstrap.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thank you, I forgot 2 JavaScript files.